# ¿Comó automatizar la extraccion de eventos de vistas personalizadas con windows powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, optimización, log, rdp

deseo implementar una linea de comandos utiilizando Windows PowerShell que me permita automatizar la extraccion de eventos de vistas personalizadas.
Esta es la linea de comando que estoy intentando implementar:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shwFc.png)

```
PS C:\Users\radmin> Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path="C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Remote-Desktop-Management-Service%4Operational.evtx"; ID=24; StartTime=(Get-Date).AddDays(-5)} | Sort-Object TimeCreated | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\radmin\Desktop\Eventos.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

al hacerlo me aparece el siguiente error,
**Get-WinEvent : No se encontraron eventos que coincidan con los criterios de selección especificados.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1

- Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path="C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-WinEvent], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchingEventsFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWinEventCommand**
  ```

¿Cómo puedo corregirlo?

Intente utilizar rutas y LogName sin embargo ninguna me funciono, espero automatizar este proceso